# ¿Como deshabilito una columna si contiene un valor específico?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Lo que pretendo lograr es deshabilitar las columnas que tengan un determinado dato.

Html

```
   <div id="jsgrid"></div>
```

Función

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;

    $('#jsgrid').each(function () {
       //REQUIERO QUE SE BLOQUEEN TODOS AQUELLOS QUE CONTENGAN "CONTROL"
        $(this).find(".control").attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

Éste es mi jsgrid generado.

```
   $("#jsgrid").jsGrid({

    width: "100%",
    height: "auto",
    paging: true,
    center: true,
    autoload: true,
    filtering: false,
    confirmDeleting: false,
    pageSize: 15,
    editing: true,
    reload: 20,


    fields: [
        { name: "Columna1", title: 'Columna1', type: "text", width: 40, align: "center", editing:false },
        { name: "Columna2", title: 'Columna2', type: "text", width: 40, align: "center", editing: false },

         {
             type: "control", deleteButton: true, deleteButtonTooltip: "Rechazar", deleteButtonId: "btnRechazar",deleteButtonClass: "jsgrid-button jsgrid-cancel-edit-button",
             editButtonClass: "jsgrid-button jsgrid-update-button", editButtonId: "btnAceptar", editButtonTooltip: "Aceptar", width: 35

         }
    ]

});
```

Sobre el boton "edit" generado por el jsgrid tengo éste código

```
        onItemEditing: function (args) {

            $("#jsgrid").jsGrid('updateItem', args.item);
            var keys = Object.values(args.item);
            //alert(keys[1]);
            var key1 = keys[1];
            if (key1 == 'ACEPTADO')
            {
                alert("Ok");
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            }

        },
```

Al dar clic sobre el botón, "key1" me devuelve el valor de de la columna[1] de la fila seleccionada, Key1 es el valor por el cual necesito definir si la fila se bloquea o no. (Todas las filas que tengan el valor de Key1 = ACEPTADO deben estar deshabilitadas), no he podido implementar ésto sobre el document.ready, que considero una buena idea, ya que recorrería todo el jsgrid en busca de ese valor.

Sí alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres deshabilitar?

Comment: toda la fila @AlvaroMontoro que contenga un tipo control, (en mi caso todos)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando esta línea:

```
  $(this).find("control").attr('disabled', true);
```

Por esta otra:

```
  $(this).find("control").prop('disabled', true);
```

Y fijate si estas posicionando en el elemento adecuado al momento de hacer el each, por lo general para saber donde estoy para siempre hago un console.log() del elemento que quiero visualizar. 
Saludos!.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FernandoCampos ya lo había intentado y aún así no me deshabilita nada, también lo intenté así $(this).find("control").attr('disabled', true);
            $(this).find("control").prop('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: Vale amigo, no me di cuenta pero el tema es que a su clase control le falta el punto para especificar que esto es una clase css y no un tag de html. Saludos!.

Answer (score 0):

El código siguiente tiene varios problemas:

```
$('jsgrid').each(function () {
   //REQUIERO QUE SE BLOQUEEN TODOS AQUELLOS QUE CONTENGAN "CONTROL"
    $(this).find("control").attr('disabled', true);
});
```

De primeras, el selector principal no va a funcionar. Tienes un elemento con ID `jsgrid`, pero estás intentando seleccionar un elemento con la etiqueta `jsgrid`. Falta el `#` para indicar que es un ID: `$("#jsgrid").each` con lo que quedaría así:

```
$('#jsgrid').each(function () {
   //REQUIERO QUE SE BLOQUEEN TODOS AQUELLOS QUE CONTENGAN "CONTROL"
    $(this).find("control").attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Algo similar ocurre con el `find`: estás intentando seleccionar la etiqueta `control` que no existe. Parecería que lo que quieres es seleccionar la clase `control` por lo que deberías añadir un `.` así:

```
$('#jsgrid').each(function () {
   //REQUIERO QUE SE BLOQUEEN TODOS AQUELLOS QUE CONTENGAN "CONTROL"
    $(this).find(".control").attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Hasta aquí, esos dos errores casi podrían considerarse fallos tipográficos. Potencialmente hay otro problema: ¿qué es lo que quieres deshabilitar? ¿El `jsgrid`, el `control` u otra cosa? Ten en cuenta que en cuanto haces `.find(algo)` el elemento sujeto a la acción es el encontrado y no el elemento que lo contiene.

Pero por cómo defines la pregunta, parece que lo que quieres deshabilitar es otra cosa (¿la columna?), por lo que deberías hacer otra comprobación más, para deshabilitar el contenedor y no el contenido, o usar otra funciona como `contains()` en lugar de `find()`.

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro, olvidé corregirlo aquí, y tienes razón también olvidé utilizar el "." para la clase, lo que requiero deshabilitar es toda la fila, o si hay alguna forma unicamente los botones que tengan un valor determinado, ejemplo, deshabilitar todos aquellos en los que la Columna1 = "x";  $('#jsgrid tbody tr').each(function () {
           // $(this).find("td:eq(0)").find("input").attr('disabled', true);
            $(this).find(".control").attr('disabled', true);
            $(this).find(".control").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }); no tengo idea de cómo lograrlo

Comment: @masha10 no es lo mismo la fila que la columna, ¿qué es lo que quieres deshabilitar? Por un lado dices columna, por otro dices fila, en el jQuery que compartes parece los inputs de cierta columna, o todos los inputs de todas las filas... Debes aclarar eso primero: ¿qué quieres conseguir?¿qué has realizado? ¿cómo ha fallado?

Comment: he anidado más información a mi pregunta. Gracias